# ambari cluster + poor connection between ambari-agent to ambari server

Tags: ambari, hdp

we have ambari cluster with 872 data-nodes machines , when ambari version is 2.6.x

we have for now some network problem ,

after long investigation we found that , ambari agent that runs on some machine not communicate well with the ambari server

therefore we get some strange behaviors as 5 dead data-nodes from ambari dashboard , ***while for sure datanodes machine are healthy***

is it possible to give more tolerated value in ambari agent configuration so the ack between ambari agent to ambari server will be after more little time in order to ignore the network problems ?

something like timeout or time connection between the ambari agent to ambari server

Comment: You have other issues here than this setting you are seeking.  I seen a post similar to this in Cloudera Community, someone specific mention same number of data nodes.  872 nodes requires some very specific performance tuning.  I would recommend you guys excerciser your cloudera support license or reach out to someone like DFHEINZ for cluster evaluation, tuning, and high availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the root cause of the issue why Data Node is showing as Dead.

1. Ambari agent runs on every node. It is responsible for sending
   metrics and heartbeat to the Ambari server which then publishes to
   your Ambari web UI.
2. The name node waits for 10 minutes till it declares the data node as dead and copies
   the blocks to other data nodes.
3. If it's showing that data node is dead then please check the Ambari agent status in
   the specific node by running-`service ambari-agent status`. Parallelly you can check the `ambari-agent.log` in the worker node to check why Ambari agent stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your http timeouts in ambari-agents for service tasks, http timeouts

https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-agent/conf/unix/ambari-agent.ini

There's a HTTP Timeout section you can configure it based on your network throughput.

The file should be in /etc/ambari-agent/ambari.properties

Comment: https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-agent/conf/unix/ambari-agent.ini